# Generate PDF using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf, phalcon

i am working with phalcon php framework. I want to send data displayed in a div tag(it is a result of a search)to controller function, and controller will generate pdf file. But, pdf file is not generating.
Here is my view:

```
       var imenica = "Ja se zovem Nedim Omerbegovic";
       $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo  $this->url->get("test/creatingpdf");?>',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: '',
        data: {imenica:imenica},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            } ,
            error: function(){
                alert("Greska");
            }

    });


    });
```

and here is code for controller:

```
    public function creatingpdfAction(){
    $this->view->disable();
    $string =$_POST['imenica'];
    $this->view->setVars(array('ime'=>$string));

          $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
    $loader->registerClasses(
     array(
    "mpdf"=> "C:/wamp/www/phalcon1/mpdf/mpdf.php"
 )
 );


    $loader->register();
    //$string = "Ja se zovem Nedim Omerbegovic";
    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
    $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');
    $cont = $this->view->getRender('test', 'creatingpdf');
    //generisanje pdf dokumenta
    $pdf = new mpdf();
    $pdf->WriteHTML($cont, 2);
    $br = rand(0,100000);
    $ispis = "Pobjeda Rudet-Izvjestaj-".$br;
    $pdf->Output($ispis, 'I');
  }
```

How can i see generated pdf file in this way of warking

Answer (score 0):

Look at TCPDF @ http://www.tcpdf.org/ for a PDF library that definitely works with Phalcon. While this is not a Phalcon specific question (since Phalcon doesn't have a native PDF library), you can certainly integrate it in with Phalcon. If you wanted to do that, you could register the TCPDF library as a service with Phalcon and include the library in the autoloader just like you would any other service.

Example:

```
$di->set('tcpdf', function() {
    $tcpdf = new TCPDF();

    return $tcpdf;
});
```

which will make your library accessible by

```
$this->tcpdf
```

in an object that extends core Phalcon functionality or

```
\Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->getTcpdf();
```

statically.

Comment: thanks, but mpdf works with phalcon too, but my problem is that this works fine when i call method using Tag::submitButton, but how can i achieve to see generated pdf using ajax call.