# JavaScript: create Pdf from div (HTML and plain text, no images)

Tags: javascript, html, pdf-generation

I would like to add a function to a page that export a certain div content to PDf. 
My div only contains a table, standard HTML and plain text, no images or iframes etc.

Through Google and the search here I came across jsPdf but that seems to be a large file to include.

Can anyone recommend a (free) alternative to this or help me to write a function myself ?

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery plugin can help you:

```
http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF
```

Or

check it [Generate PDF using jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211917/generate-pdf-using-jquery-ajax)